# Doctrine many-to-many relationship wants to create a table twice when I create a migration

Tags: doctrine, symfony

Before I describe my problem, it might actually make it clearer if I start with the error I'm getting:

```
$ ./app/console doc:mig:diff

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                 
  The table with name 'user_media_area' already exists.
```

That's absolutely true - `user_media_area` does exist. I created it in a previous migration and I don't understand why Symfony is trying to create the table again.

My problem has something to do with a many-to-many relationship. I have a table called `user`, a table called `media_area` and a table called `user_media_area`.

Here's the code where I tell `user` about `media_area` (`Entity/User.php`):

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MediaArea", inversedBy="mediaAreas")
 * @JoinTable(name="user_media_area",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="media_area_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $mediaAreas;
```

And here's where I tell `media_area` about `user` (`Entity/MediaArea.php`):

```
/** 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="users")
 */
private $users;
```

What's interesting is that if I remove that `JoinTable` stuff from `Entity/User.php`, `./app/console doctrine:migrations:diff` will work again:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MediaArea", inversedBy="mediaAreas")
 */
private $mediaAreas;
```

However, it's a little off: it now wants to create a new table called `mediaarea`, which I don't want. My table already exists and it's called `media_area`.

So it looks like either way, Symfony is trying to create a table based on this `ManyToMany` thing in my `User` class, and the only reason the problem goes away when I remove the `JoinTable` is that the name of the table it wants to create (`mediaarea`) no longer matches the actual name of my table (`media_area`).

So my question is: **Why does it want to create a new table at all? What am I doing wrong?**

(I know it's possible that my naming conventions are off. Symfony and Doctrine's database examples are frustratingly devoid of multi-term column names, so I don't always know if I'm supposed to do `media_area` or `mediaArea`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Association Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/association-mapping.html) explanation on the official docs, the `@JoinColumn` and `@JoinTable` definitions are usually optional and have sensible default values, being:

```
name: "<fieldname>_id"
referencedColumnName: "id"
```

From that we can conclude that there is really **no concrete difference** between the two implementations you presented.

However, when it comes to migration, the creation of the table is a pretty common and expected behaviour. The thing is the table should always get deleted and created again, which is not happenning.

About the table name issue, the default behaviour of Doctrine 2 about this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MediaArea", inversedBy="mediaAreas")
 */
private $mediaAreas;
```

Is to try and create a table called `mediaarea`. Again, perfectly normal.

If you want to declare a specific name for the table of an entity, you should do this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_table")
 */
class Something
```

I'm not sure if that helps you at all, but I guess it puts you, at least, on the right track.

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer? It does not answer OP's question on how to stop doctrine from showing that error. Upon adding this I got Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException : [Semantical Error] Annotation @ORM\Table is not allowed to be declared on property User::$mediaAreas. You may only use this annotation on these code elements: CLASS.

Comment: You are trying to put the `@ORM/Table` annotation on the property level, while it should be placed on the class level. The error has nothing to do with either the question or the answer.

Comment: @DanielRibeiro actualy, it does - you showed on the property that it's \@Table, which is incorrect.

Comment: so if you delete the table (drop), why does it still says that the table exists?