# Why does doctrine migration try to create 2 tables on a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

I have declared a ManyToMany relation between 2 entities, and when I use doctrine:migrations:diff, it tries to create the table twice and throws an exception "The table with name 'incompass.surgerysurgeryside' already exists"

This is the annotation that I have used:

Surgery.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Incompass\SurgeryBundle\Entity\SurgerySide", inversedBy="surgeries")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="SurgerySurgerySide",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="surgery_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="surgery_side_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $surgery_sides;
```

SurgerySide.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Incompass\SurgeryBundle\Entity\Surgery", inversedBy="surgery_sides")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="SurgerySurgerySide",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="surgery_side_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="surgery_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $surgeries;
```

(NB The answers here don't answer the actual question [Doctrine many-to-many relationship wants to create a table twice when I create a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916391/doctrine-many-to-many-relationship-wants-to-create-a-table-twice-when-i-create-a))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `inversedBy` or use once `inversedBy` and once `mappedBy`.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Incompass\SurgeryBundle\Entity\SurgerySide", inversedBy="surgeries")
 */
 protected $surgery_sides;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Incompass\SurgeryBundle\Entity\Surgery", mappedBy="surgery_sides")
 */
protected $surgeries;
```

#### Explanation

Doctrine guesses how to name table, usually with priority `<firstEntity>_<secondEntity>`. Since both are `inversedBy`, Doctrine doesn't know, which to use the second, thus creates two tables.